Image not found in my Django Project (only in one of the 2 pages)
i'm trying to display an home image at top of the page but it doesn't work. I have the same image in an other page and it works. also if i hold mouse on image source link on the ide it says me that the path is correct.  . :
Here is the line code (path in the images):
<p><img src="../media/images/home.png" width="30px" alt="home image">HOME</p>

Don't use relative paths.

Relative paths are probably the culprit: if you visit a page that has more slashes, then the .. thus points to a different directory.
Use absolute paths, so: /media/… instead of ../media/….
